# return a String from firestore for an enum in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the json_serialization package. I have an enum ..

```
enum OrderStatus {
     @JsonValue("Pending") PENDING,
  @JsonValue("Preparing") PREPARING,
  @JsonValue("Completed") COMPLETED,
  @JsonValue("Cancelled") CANCELLED,
}
```

The generated file (part .g file) looks fine. The OrderStatus is stored as a string in Firestore. I want to present the status in a Text() widget. But

```
Text(order.orderStatus)
```

won't compile. Obviously the text widget needs a string and it's receiving a enum. I know I can use a extension method to convert to a string. But I thought the annotations could handle converting to a string. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `order.orderStatus.toString()` but the output will be **order.orderStatus**
if you want to have **orderStatus** as the output without order. use this:

```
order.orderStatus.toString().replaceAll('order.','')
```